# Azure VPN vs. Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec, ike

I have a Cisco 5516-x with v9.7(1)21 on my end and I am trying to create a working VPN to Azure. It looks to me like phase1 goes well but phase2 fails due to policy mismatch.

Any suggestions for how I should change my Azure and/or ASA config to get this working?

Thanks for any suggestions as to how I can solve this!

**Debug:**

```
# sh crypto ikev2 sa          
IKEv2 SAs:
Session-id:44876, Status:UP-IDLE, IKE count:1, CHILD count:0
Tunnel-id                 Local                Remote     Status         Role
851718313      <CiscoPubIP>/500     <AzurePubIP>/500      READY    RESPONDER
  Encr: AES-CBC, keysize: 256, Hash: SHA384, DH Grp:24, Auth sign: PSK, Auth verify: PSK
  Life/Active Time: 86400/32 sec

#debug crypto ikev2 protocol 127
....
IKEv2-PROTO-2: (554): Processing IKE_AUTH message
IKEv2-PROTO-1: (554): Failed to find a matching policy
IKEv2-PROTO-1: (554): Received Policies: 
ESP: Proposal 1:  AES-CBC-256 SHA96 Don't use ESN
IKEv2-PROTO-1: (554): Failed to find a matching policy
IKEv2-PROTO-1: (554): Expected Policies: 
IKEv2-PROTO-5: (554): Failed to verify the proposed policies
IKEv2-PROTO-1: (554): Failed to find a matching policy
....
```

**Azure Config**

```
$IPSecpolicy    = New-AzureRmIpsecPolicy -IkeEncryption AES256 -IkeIntegrity SHA384 -DhGroup DHGroup24 -IpsecEncryption AES256 -IpsecIntegrity SHA1 -PfsGroup PFS24 -SALifeTimeSeconds 28800 -SADataSizeKilobytes 102400000;
```

**Cisco-config**

```
access-list outside_access_in extended permit ip host <azurePubIP> host <CiscoPubIP>

crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES-256
  protocol esp encryption aes-256
  protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
  protocol esp encryption des
  protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
  protocol esp encryption 3des
  protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
  protocol esp encryption aes
  protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
  protocol esp encryption aes-192
  protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
  protocol esp encryption aes-256
  protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5

crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 102400000
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto ipsec inner-routing-lookup

crypto dynamic-map default_map 65535 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES AES-256
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic default_map

crypto isakmp identity address 
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ikev2 policy 2
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha384
 group 24     
 prf sha384
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-192
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2    
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 50
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha256
 group 2
 prf sha256 sha
 lifetime seconds 86400  

crypto ikev2 enable outside

tunnel-group <AzurePubIP> type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group <AzurePubIP> ipsec-attributes
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *****
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *****
no tunnel-group-map enable peer-ip
```

Comment: I don't see a crypto map entry for your Azure tunnel.  It can't form Phase 2 without that.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the corresponding crypto map statements for that tunnel.  Without the crypto map statements, you can't form Phase 2.  Dynamic tunnels, like you were asking about, are only for when your IP address is dynamic (rather than static), on one end, such as if your ISP assigns you an IP address via DHCP, and your ASA would be the initiator (it could never be the receiver) for all tunnels configured on it, because its IP address would not be permanently known.  Unless that's your case here, you should have something like:

```
crypto map outside_map 1 match address <access list for interesting traffic>
crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs <DH group Azure says to use>
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer <azure peer IP>
crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal <proposal to use>
```

Comment: I tried this also but it makes no difference. I wonder if it might be somehow related to my dynamic map (see config above) ? The commands above should be crypto map outside_map 1 <rest> btw.

Comment: Sorry. Yeah. Was just typing and not paying attention to the order.  I'll fix it.

Comment: As for the rest you said, it could be related.  If you're not actually using dynamic tunnels I'd remove that stuff if for nothing more than to have a cleaner config file.

Comment: Can you show us what you had tried that didn't work?

Comment: crypto map outside_map 1 match address <ACLnamewithAzurePubIPonly>
crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs group24
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer <remoteIP>
crypto map outside_map 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES-256

Comment: @AndyThompson That does look correct. You can try to put that back in and remove the dynamic VPN stuff to see if it does make a difference.  It really shouldn't since the map sequence number is much higher.  The part that is likely causing A problem (maybe not the only problem) is that you've got `no tunnel-group-map enable peer-ip` which could be causing it to not find a matching ID for both phase 1 and phase 2.

Comment: I will give it a go tomorrow and let you know how it went. I seems plausible as only one map can be given to a single interface in this scenario, or so I for some reason believe. We'll see :)

Comment: @AndyThompson One map name. Not sequence number. You can have thousands of tunnels on a single interface, as long as they each have a unique sequence number. You just can't have something like outside_map and simultaneously have something like outside_map2 tied to the same interface.